# Can I use two possessive nouns in a sentence?

Tags: compound-possessives

I'm writing a very brief description for a job duty. Is it grammatically correct to use two possessive nouns in a sentence (e.g., Administration's and company's)?

Full sentence is...
They support, strategize, and promote  the Administration's and company's programs, initiatives, and campaigns.

Comment: Why couldn't you?

Comment: Wasn't sure if the correct use was: Administration's and company's...OR...Administration and company's    where the apostrophe should be on both nouns or the 2nd noun

Answer (score 2):

According to Cambridge Dictionary,

> We can use two possessive ’s constructions in the same noun phrase:
>
> We went to Jake’s father’s funeral.

When two nouns possess the same entity, add the apostrophe only to the second one:

Jason and Kate's children

But when two nouns possess different entities, you need to add an apostrophe to both:

Jason's and Jimmy's children